# (403) Access Not Configured when adding event to calendar

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, oauth-2.0

Today I started to get this error upon adding new events to calendar:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'apiServiceException' with message
 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/
calendars/[cal-id]@group.calendar.google.com/events?alt=json&key=[dev-key]:
 (403) Access Not Configured' in /[...]/src/io/apiREST.php:86
 Stack trace: #0 /[...]/src/io/apiREST.php(56): apiREST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(apiHttpRequest)) 
 #1 /[...]/src/service/apiServiceResource.php(148): apiREST::execute(Object(apiServiceRequest)) #2 /[...]/src/contrib/apiCalendarService.php(472): 
apiServiceResource->__call('insert', Array) #3 /[...]/index.php(160): EventsServiceResource->insert('[cal-id-part]...', 
Object(Ev in /[...]/src/io/apiREST.php on line 86
```

It worked perfectly till now and I didn't change anything in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, they released new version and that what apparently caused errors. Got the newest version now and it works great once again.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem accessing Google Analytics data with PHP. I fixed it by making sure the Analytics service was turned on for my project in my API console: https://code.google.com/apis/console/.

You may have to turn on the calendar service. See the link below for further explanation when someone had an issue with the translation service:

[Translation api has stopped working](http://groups.google.com/group/google-ajax-search-api/browse_thread/thread/1ab6a5ed4e019505)

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this will help someone.
I had the same error and I had tried everything. Then I removed "developer_key" from config.php and it worked. Please note I was using Service Account https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: Thank you!  Been searching for the problem all day.  I'm using calendar API via PHP client.  This code used to work but at some point stopped, commenting out `$client->setDeveloperKey('...')` was the ticket

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help someone, either.

It may also help to go to the respective calendar-settings page in your Google Account, edit something trivial and explicitly save again, (or re-save once more  to set back to the old settings). Sometimes the google servers are a bit hesitant to accept any  new settings, especially the "Sharing " settings. Check which of your service accounts have permission levels "can edit" , or "is owner" .