# Google Search response.items.length error

Tags: php, javascript, rest

EDIT:
This is the page where you can find all the error stuff:
http://google.intellectproductions.com/

I'm using this example for Google Search API:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSON/Atom Custom Search API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
      function hndlr(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        var item = response.items[i];
        // in production code, item.htmlTitle should have the HTML entities escaped.
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.htmlTitle;
      }
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=YOUR-KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=cars&callback=hndlr">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, that has a flaw in it and I have no idea why.

My script tag url is this:

```
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={{MY KEY}}&cx=012495781369301842149:acs-gv099hu&q=runescape&callback=hndlr">
</script>
```

But with both examples it is giving me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Why would they post something that has an error in it?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(response);`? Or any kind of debugging at all?

Comment: Whenever I paste that code inside the function for the first line to be read, it just keeps showing a blank page with no helpful information.

Comment: It just says [object Object]

Comment: In which browser? You should be able to click on it and get its properties…

Comment: I'm in Chrome.. It just says this:
hndlr googlesearch.localhost:12
(anonymous function)

Comment: Sorry, where are you putting it? That sounds like a stack trace.

Comment: IT says something like 403

Comment: error: Object
code: 403
errors: Array[1]
0: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
message: "Access Not Configured"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: So you haven’t configured the API yet, I’d assume. Is the key right and active? Did you follow all the steps? Is there a domain restriction that’s not being met? (I don’t remember much about how Google APIs work.)

Comment: I just generated a new key and did that one and it's giving me the same error. It has nothing to do with the key. The response.items.length is the part that is throwing the error because it's not catching any value for response.

Comment: It’s giving you an error message that’s pretty descriptive — I would still assume it has something to do with your service. Have you tried [looking the error up](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=403+Access+Not+Configured)? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498084/403-access-not-configured-when-adding-event-to-calendar), for example, seems promising.

Comment: Yes I have tried looking everywhere hence the reason I posted here.. I've been at this for the past 3 hours..

Comment: Now it's giving me an error code of 400

Comment: Everytime I refresh it gives me a new error code. Now its 403